# Doctrine orWhere for multiple columns

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to fetch using doctrine, my entity has three date values, expiryDate, scheduledDate, addedDate(mandatory). I need to check first is there any row having scheduledDate as today , If no then I need to check for entry before expiryDate which has the latest addedDate.
      I try this code ,

```
public function getLatestEntry(){
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb ->select('MyEntry')
        ->from('MyEntry', 'myEntry')
        ->Where('myEntry.scheduledOn = :today')
        ->orWhere('myEntry.expirationDate >= :today')
        ->orWhere('myEntry.expirationDate is null')
        ->orderby('myEntry.addedDate')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->setParameters(array('today' => $today));

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

But I didn't get the result I expected ,I feel like the first where condition has been ignored, How can I tackle this?

Comment: Are you sure that result is wrong?) Are you try to execute this query in WorkBench?

Comment: Yes I am Sure,In work bench also I got the same

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have 3 conditions with equal priority. If one of these is true the row is fetched. But you want your conditions with different priorities. Either the first one matches or it does not match and second matches. Not that your third condition is part of your second one:

```
$qb ->select('MyEntry')
    ->from('MyEntry', 'myEntry')
    ->Where('myEntry.scheduledOn = :today')
    ->orWhere('(myEntry.scheduledOn != :today AND (myEntry.expirationDate >= :today OR myEntry.expirationDate IS NULL))')
    ->orderby('myEntry.addedDate')
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->setParameters(array('today' => $today));
```

**EDIT:**
I'm not quite shure if you want to have entries with expiration date NULL equally treated as the ones with an expiration date set. If its not equal for you, you could alter your `ORDER BY` clause like

```
->orderby('myEntry.addedDate', 'ASC')
->addOrderBy('my.Entry.expirationDate', 'DESC')
```

Comment: still I get the result of the third orWhere condition,  after comment out that I got the correct result,But there may be some condition that expirationDate and scheduledDate may null.

Comment: If first condition is true ,normally it can't come to second , but here it happening,is it a bug?

Comment: 3. condition is a bit weird, look at [comparison with NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html). It should never add any rows, since comparing with `NULL` is always `NULL`, so `CONDITION 1 AND NULL` == `NULL`. I update my answer.

Comment: I am realy confused with this, If first condition satisfy is it check second ?

Comment: No. The `orWhere(condition_1)->orWhere(condition_2)` will result in a mysql statement like `WHERE condition_1 OR condition_2`. So if condition 1 is fulfilled, condition 2 is not checked anymore, since the WHERE clause is already TRUE.